# Remove icons and retain remaining code

Tags: html

I have this below code but There is an facebook and google+ icon in the code I want to remove those code and retain the login part code but when ever I comment the facebook and google+ icons the login code does not work can anyone help

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Register/login to Student Space</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css" type="text/css"/>





</head>

<body>


    <div class="logmod">
        <div class="logmod__wrapper">
            <span class="logmod__close">Close</span>
            <div class="logmod__container">
                <ul class="logmod__tabs">
                    <li data-tabtar="lgm-2"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    <li data-tabtar="lgm-1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
                    <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
                        <div class="logmod__heading">
                            <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your details here<strong>to create an account</strong></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="logmod__form">
                            <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                                <div class="sminputs">
                                    <div class="input full">
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Username*</label>
                                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" size="50" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sminputs">
                                    <div class="input string optional">
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input string optional">
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
                                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="simform__actions">
                                    <input class="sumbit" type="submit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Create Account" />
                                    <!--  <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms & Privacy</a></span>-->
                                </div> 
                            </form>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="logmod__alter">
                           <!-- <div class="logmod__alter-container">-->
                              <!--  <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                                    <div class="connect__icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="connect__context">
                                        <span>Create an account with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                                <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                                    <div class="connect__icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="connect__context">
                                        <span>Create an account with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2">
                        <div class="logmod__heading">
                            <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="logmod__form">
                            <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                                <div class="sminputs">
                                    <div class="input full">
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sminputs">
                                    <div class="input full">
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                                        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50" />
                                        <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="simform__actions">
                                    <input class="sumbit" type="submit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Log In" />
                                    <span class="simform__actions-sidetext"><a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a></span>
                                </div> 
                            </form>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="logmod__alter">
                            <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                                <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                                    <div class="connect__icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="connect__context">
                                        <span>Sign in with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                                    <div class="connect__icon">
                                        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="connect__context">
                                        <span>Sign in with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons are added with the following `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`
                    `<i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>`
                    `<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>`
                    `<i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>`
Remove them and the icons will be gone

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Register/login to Student Space</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css" type="text/css" />





</head>

<body>


  <div class="logmod">
    <div class="logmod__wrapper">
      <span class="logmod__close">Close</span>
      <div class="logmod__container">
        <ul class="logmod__tabs">
          <li data-tabtar="lgm-2"><a href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li data-tabtar="lgm-1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
          <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
            <div class="logmod__heading">
              <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your details here<strong>to create an account</strong></span>
            </div>
            <div class="logmod__form">
              <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                <div class="sminputs">
                  <div class="input full">
                    <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Username*</label>
                    <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" size="50" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sminputs">
                  <div class="input string optional">
                    <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                    <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="input string optional">
                    <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
                    <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="simform__actions">
                  <input class="sumbit" type="submit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Create Account" />
                  <!--  <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms & Privacy</a></span>-->
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="logmod__alter">
              <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                  <div class="connect__icon">
                  </div>
                  <div class="connect__context">
                  </div>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                  <div class="connect__icon">
                  </div>
                  <div class="connect__context">
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2">
            <div class="logmod__heading">
              <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
            </div>
            <div class="logmod__form">
              <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
                <div class="sminputs">
                  <div class="input full">
                    <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                    <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sminputs">
                  <div class="input full">
                    <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                    <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50" />
                    <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="simform__actions">
                  <input class="sumbit" type="submit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Log In" />
                  <span class="simform__actions-sidetext"><a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a></span>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="logmod__alter">
              <div class="logmod__alter-container">
                <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
                  <div class="connect__icon">
                  </div>
                  <div class="connect__context">
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
                  <div class="connect__icon">
                  </div>
                  <div class="connect__context">
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>
```

Comment: But the problem is I dont want those FB and google+ icons or any of its informations by adding style i.e Display: none it is not displaying the login module too

Comment: Not only Icons the whole information about the Facebook and google+ must be hiden

Comment: I edited the answer to remove only the social  icons.

Comment: No I don't want any code relating to Facebook and google+ like "Create your account using facebook" and stuff I just want a login and registration form to be displayed

Comment: How about now, I removed text related to google and facebook, lemme know if it's ok or if an unwanted space is created